# file upload directory not created in my vps

Tags: codeigniter

file upload directory not created in my vps its show me blank page in error massege 
Here is my code.

```
$dir_exist = true; // flag for checking the directory exist or not
                if (!is_dir('./assets/uploads/profile_pictures/' . $id))
                {
                    mkdir('./assets/uploads/profile_pictures/' . $id, 0777, true);
                    $dir_exist = false; // dir not exist
                }
                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('upload_profile_picture'))
                {
                        if(!$dir_exist)
                        rmdir('./assets/uploads/profile_pictures/' . $id);

                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        //$this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error[1]);
                        print_r($error);
                }
                else
                {
                      $upload_data =  $this->upload->data();
                        $new_name=$upload_data['file_name'];
                        //$this->session->set_flashdata('error', $data[1]);
                }
                if($new_name=='0'){
                    $new_name=$temp_profile_pic;
                }
```

Comment: What about using FCPATH like `mkdir(FCPATH . 'assets/uploads/profile_pictures/' . $id, 0777, true);` But I am not sure where you have set the $id variable use FCPATH on is_dir also

Comment: i find the issue with directory permission and also added `FCPATH` on my server thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = str_replace( ':', '', $date);
    if (!is_dir('uploads/'.$date)) {
    mkdir('./uploads/' . $date, 0777, TRUE);
}
```

Please try above code and check if this code is working then definately the issue is different.
and check the id is not getting `:` either it will never created new dir.

Here is the reference: https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/codeigniter-php-create-directory-if-does-not-exist-example

Comment: i find the issue with directory permission on my server thanks for your time

Comment: please give upvote if it is useful, thanks.
and never forgot to check the file permission whenever you are working with PHP projects.